# JointJS - Mouse click event triggers cell position change event

Tags: javascript, svg, jquery-svg, jointjs

I need to define **mouse click event** for my each cell. I used `cell:pointerup` event; but this event is triggered when I **change positions of cells** too. How can I differentiate these 2 events?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is to create a **custom element view** and distinct click from dragging by checking whether a `pointermove` event was triggered between `pointerdown` and `pointerup` events.

```
var ClickableView = joint.dia.ElementView.extend({
  pointerdown: function () {
    this._click = true;
    joint.dia.ElementView.prototype.pointerdown.apply(this, arguments);
  },
  pointermove: function () {
    this._click = false;
    joint.dia.ElementView.prototype.pointermove.apply(this, arguments);
  },
  pointerup: function (evt, x, y) {
    if (this._click) {
      // triggers an event on the paper and the element itself
      this.notify('cell:click', evt, x, y); 
    } else {
      joint.dia.ElementView.prototype.pointerup.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  }
});
```

And then tell the `joint.dia.Paper` to use the view.

```
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
  // el, width, height etc.
  elementView: ClickableView
});
```

A fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kumilingus/6umUH/).

Comment: What if I wanted to apply this view only to a certain Model, not everything on paper? How should I proceed?