# jointjs element mouse click event

Tags: javascript, html, jointjs

I'm using `jointjs` to draw graphs.

I'm wondering how to listen to the mouse click event on an element?
I found on http://www.jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Element, there is only `change:position` option but no onclick option lol.

There's only `cell:pointerclick` option on the whole paper instead of the single element.

How can I achieve only listen to mouse click element on the single element? (Say I want to resize the paper after the click)
Thanks!

Comment: Doe this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286603/jointjs-mouse-click-event-triggers-cell-position-change-event

Comment: I saw this. But how to apply to a single element instead of the whole paper? thanks

Comment: In short, you don't. The paper provides all the event handlers. This is a good thing. You can add 500 nodes and still have one handler. You can derive your own shapes from the JointJS shapes with `.extend()`. In the event handler on Paper, you can check the type of the cell and apply type-specific behavior. For instance-specific behavior, you'd still do it in the same handler, but attach attributes to the node that the handler can consult.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **pointerclick** event to capture the click events on elements. The **view** is passed as a parameter to the function and you can obtain the model of the view through **cellView.model**

```
paper.on('cell:pointerclick', function (cellView) {
   // your logic goes here
);
```

Answer (score 4):

A way to do that it's using classes and javascript events, look:

First, you assign a class to the joint js element via markup , for example a class called 'myclass' in this case:

```
var rect1 = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
markup: '<g class="rotatable"><g class="scalable"><image id="myrect1"  class="myclass"/></g><text/></g>',
    size: { width: 30, height: 73.2 },
    attrs: { 
        rect: { fill: bgcolor1,'stroke-width': 0 },

    }
});
```

Then, you capture the click event on that class objects via javascript, not in the canvas but in the document :

```
$(document).on('click', '.myclass', function () {
        //alert('yayy!');
});
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 2):

you need to listen on `view` not on the `model`. Trace all caught events on the element:

```
var a = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
    size: { width: 100, height: 100 },
    position: { x: 300, y: 300 }
}).addTo(graph);

paper.findViewByModel(a).on('all', function() {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vtalas/0z6jyq70/